# Relay destroyed

Tags: relay

I am using a DYAD CP Clare DSS4 1A05, normally open, relay. The datasheet can be downloaded

I am new to using relays. These seem to be the important specifications:

Coil Voltage: 5V Typical -- 10V Maximum
Operate Voltage & Release voltage: 0.8V Minimum -- 3.75V Maximum

Here is my circuit:

[image: Relay Circuit]

Where
- R0, R1, R2, and R3 are relays of concern
- I0, I1, I2, and I4 are inputs which can be 5V to close the switch or 0V to open the switch.
- The left and right motors are 12 volts dc motors.

The problem is, the relays got destroyed too often, usually after a day of use. That is, the two armature terminals of 1 or 2 relays get normally open (and cannot be closed anymore), and some get normally closed (and cannot be opened anymore). I don't know what I lack here.

I tried reducing the +12 and -12 volts to +- 6V, and the dc motors replaced with 3 volts, but still the same problem.

What do you know about this matter?

Comment: In what way were they "destroyed"?  Coil burned out?  Contacts welded or fused together?  What?

Comment: Also, what is the current draw of the motors?

Comment: Your link doesn't go to the datasheet.  It seems to go to some datasheet search engine.  Do it right and fix your question to point to the actual datasheet.

Comment: @Majenko. Edited. Some relays gets their contacts welded and some are fused together. Current draw of the motor is the typical one, range of 0.3-1.0 A.

Comment: Sounds like Olin's explanations may be correct to my mind.

Comment: @OlinLathrop: Edited..

Comment: @NeigylNoval, have you tried breaking apart the damaged relays and see if any of the coils are damaged?

Comment: @Kortuk: While anything is possible, it's very rare for a relay coil to break.  It's basically impossible to hurt the coil of a 12V relay by driving it on/off with 12V as often as you want.  Intead of taking the relay apart, listen for a click.  Even if the contacts have welded, there should still be something audible as the coil is switched on and off.  When relays break, it's just about always the contacts or part of the mechanical mechanism.  Coils of wire don't break unless you so something very unusual or way out of spec.

Comment: @OlinLathrop, I have found faulted relays by looking into them as ours are often clear to show the components. I just thought it was possible that taking it apart may narrow down the location of the damage. I will admit coil was a terrible word for what I thought might be damaged, I meant any part of the electrical system but this happens to me often when I type tired.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are two obvious possibilities:

You aren't doing break before make properly.  You need a delay between turning off one relay and turning on the next.  It's quite possible that one relay can turn on faster than the other turns off, leaving a dead short thru both relays for a little while.

You are switching a inductive load but not giving any place for the inductor current to go when switching off.  Relays are intended to handle this to some extent, but at the least this will cause arcing when the contacts open.  Two reverse Schottky diodes to the two supply rails for each motor will fix this problem.

### Added:

Here is a schematic showing how the reverse diodes should be connected:

[image]

Comment: For #1. I intentionally tried opening all 4 relays together at one time and close them together. I did it many times. The relays were not destroyed at those instants. During normal operation (as you suggested by adding delay), at some unknown instance, the relays got destroyed.  

For #2. Can you give example circuit or a link for that?

Comment: What's with the downvote?  What exactly do you think is wrong with what I said?

Comment: @OlinLathrop, I am not sure why, but at least 4 others disagreed, a win of 38 rep.

Comment: @Kortuk: That's not the real point.  This stack exchange system is broken as long as someone can anonymously downvote without explanation.  We see random unexplained downvotes occasionally, and there is no upside to them.  I notice a correlation between having a disgreement with someone in one place and downvotes suddenly appearing elsewhere.  This system is being abused.  It's time the stack exchange folks took this seriously and put a stop to it.

Comment: @OlinLathrop: I used to be in StackOverflow and we felt the same way when random downvotes come in. But don't worry, there is nothing wrong with the system and there is no abuse. A one or two downvotes plus three or more upvotes proves that your answer is correct.

Comment: @OlinLathrop. I've come across the snubber circuit or a RC series between the terminals of the relays in parallel (http://www.industrologic.com/mechrela.htm). What do you think of this?

Comment: @OlinLathrop, if you argue with someone and they get angry and go and downvote a number of your questions they system silently removes all of the rep loss from your account and leaves them with the rep loss.

Comment: @Kortuk: But if they're clever and only do it to one or two select answers, the system can't tell.  Again, I have seen absolutely no upside in anonymous downvotes.  My answer isn't anonymous (nor should it be).  Answers are basically peer-reviewed, which is a good thing.  But then how is it right for someone to unilaterally claim a answer is wrong without the same peer review process?  This system stinks, and allows for abuse as we've seen a few times here.

Comment: @Neigyl: A RC snubber can be effective too.  Consider the motor a inductor for the purpose of switching it off.  The instantaneous inductor current will be the same right after the switch opens as it was right before.  This current times the resistance will tell you the maximum voltage it will produce accross the switch.  Ideally the capacitor is sized so that its voltage rises as charge builds up the same as the voltage accross the resistor falls off as the current decreases.  In general you make it a bit bigger than that since the exact values are hard to predict.

Comment: @Neigyl: Before figuring out the details of a snubber, I would try the diodes as I showed.  At least that will tell you whether that was the problem.  If the diodes keep the relays from failing you, know that was it.  Then you can design the snubber if you really want that instead of the diodes for some reason.  The two will have a little different characteristics in how fast they turn off the motor and deal with coasting.  If you don't care, just stick with the diodes.

Comment: @OlinLathrop, I think we discussed this some on meta, but there is not perfect way. I would also like users to be able to disagree on technical accuracy without making it of personal issue.

Comment: @OlinLathrop, is it possible to do both the snubber and the reverse schottky? What would be the effect?

Comment: @Neigyl: A snubber wouldn't do anything with the diodes in there because the diodes would clamp the voltage.  Why do you want a snubber so badly?  What is it you think it will do for you that the diodes won't?

Comment: @OlinLathrop, Your downvote is gone!